# mysql - create a summary parent row and child rows from a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table for a team sport let's say, and there are 2 members in each team. In a match, one participant from each team compete. The loser is eliminated and the winner challenges the next participant in the opposing team. When both participants in a team are eliminated, they lose.

Here is how the data for matches appear:

```
    MatchID | Team | Player | Winner 
----------------------------------------
    1        Oilers  Mike     1
    1        Rockets Joe      0
    2        Oilers  Mike     1
    2        Rockets Bob      0
```

Is it possible in SQL to create a 'parent' row that summarizes the team match?:

i.e.

```
Match             |  Score
------------------------------
Oilers vs Rockets    2-0 "parent"
Mike / Joe           1-0 "child"
Mike / Bob           1-0 "child"
```

So far, i have something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.Team," VS ",t2.Team), SUM(IF(t1.Winner=1,1,0)) as Score
FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN tbl t2
ON t1.MatchID = t2.MatchID
AND t1.Team <> t2.Team
WHERE t1.team IS NOT NULL
AND t2.team IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CONCAT(t1.Team," VS ",t2.Team)
```

This more or less gets the 'parent' row `Oilers vs Rockets` but I haven't got a clue how to show the details of the match (`Player`) directly under the parent. It's unlike anything I've done with SQL before. The goal is to eventually turn it into an expandable html table.

Comment: I have to be honest ..  This would be SO much easier with a programming language (such as PHP or Python) --  You could them nest your loops in the same fashion you nest your expandable table(s) in HTML ..  There's a little more overhead because you'll be making multiple smaller SQL calls (returns) instead of one large one, but the effort spent would be far less of a logical headache.

Comment: @Zak Do you know where I can find a sample of this in PHP pulling data from mysql? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enhance your original code a bit and use:

```
select `Match`, Score
from (
SELECT t1.Team, CONCAT(t1.Team," VS ",t2.Team) as 'Match', 
    concat(SUM(IF(t1.Winner=1,1,0)), '-',SUM(IF(t2.Winner=1,1,0)), ' "parent"') as 'Score', 1 as ord
FROM matches t1
INNER JOIN matches t2 ON t1.MatchID = t2.MatchID AND t1.Team <> t2.Team WHERE t1.team IS NOT NULL AND t2.team IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY t1.Team, CONCAT(t1.Team," VS ",t2.Team)
UNION
SELECT t1.Team, CONCAT(t1.Player," / ",t2.Player), 
    concat(SUM(IF(t1.Winner=1,1,0)), '-',SUM(IF(t2.Winner=1,1,0)), ' "child"') as 'Score', 2
FROM matches t1
INNER JOIN matches t2 ON t1.MatchID = t2.MatchID AND t1.Team <> t2.Team WHERE t1.team IS NOT NULL AND t2.team IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY t1.Team, CONCAT(t1.Player," / ",t2.Player)
) as q
ORDER BY Team, ord;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c69bfb02529df887358c4edc56c7a8c)

This kind of problem would be better to be solved in programming language though.